# Write a Python program to create and print a list where the values are first N square of numbers

Tags: python

My teacher gave me an exercise during the computing lesson in week 2:

> Write a Python program to create and print a list where the values are first N square of numbers. You are REQUIRED to implement a function named `printSquare()` to take n where n is an positive integer.

I'mm trying to writing a function called `printSquare()`.
for example, the expected output of `printSquare(5)` is `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]`.

```
def getList(num):
    list=[]
    for i in range(int(num)):
        list.append(i)
    return list

def printSquare(num):
    wholeList = list(getList(num))
    wholeList.pop(0)
    wholeList.append(num)
    tmp=[]
    for i in wholeList:
        x = wholeList[i]**2
        tmp.append(x)
    return tmp

printSquare(5)
```

I'm struggling in the following part, I don't know why the `tmp.append(x)` doesn't work.

```
for i in wholeList:
        x = wholeList[i]**2
        tmp.append(x)
    return tmp
```

The second question is that is there any faster way to write this code.

Comment: What do you mean "`tmp.append(x)` doesn't work"? What makes you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: Why are you popping 0 ?

Comment: Ask your teacher about `range` and list comprehensions (or become familiar with the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/)).

Comment: Your teacher asks you to print the output, and you are not printing anywhere.

Comment: you wholelist is empty due to you popping it's only element before reaching the for loop, so none of the code inside is executed.

Comment: There are other errors in this code, the append isnt the issue.

Comment: You're not actually printing, or otherwise outputting, the result of `printSquare(5)`. So you won't see any results of the computation done in the at function; you just throw away the result (i.e., `return tmp` is not capture and thus ignored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes and lack of understanding in the code. Let me try and explain mistakes and lack of understanding i found.

you are using `range(num)` which will give you a list from 0 to num-1. Hence you do `wholeList.pop(0)` to remove 0 from the list and `wholeList.append(num)` to then add the last num in.

Instead of that, you can do

`range(1,int(num)+1)`
This will return you a list from 1 to number, solving both the issue, and not needing to pop and add extra number to list

secondly

```
for i in wholeList:
        x = wholeList[i]**2
```

That is not how looping over list works
 `for i in wholeList:`

Will return you the element of the list, not its index. Here you are assuming i is the index of elements in list. So `wholeList[i]**2` is where your code fails, since you try to access elements at index position that does not exist.

If you want to get index position you have to do

`for index, value in enumerate(wholeList):`

This will return you the index, and the value associated with the index in the list.

I hope, all of that helped you understand things better. Here is a code that works

```
def getList(num):
    list=[]
    for i in range(1,int(num)+1):
        list.append(i)
    return list



def printSquare(num):
    wholeList = getList(num)
    tmp=[]
    for i in wholeList:
        tmp.append(i**2)
    return tmp

printSquare(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error message it states that `IndexError: list index out of range` meaning that the index isn't in the range of your list. What you could do is try to use the range function over the length of the list: `for i in range(1, len(wholeList))`, this ensures that the index is always within the range.

Answer (score 0):

when you use for..in you are directly getting elements, not indexes. So to solve the problem write

```
for i in wholeList:
    x = i**2
    tmp.append(x)
return tmp
```

Also, you can write this way more clearly with list comprehensions (and it is a nice tool to have)

```
def get_list(n):
    return [i**2 for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i` in the for loop is the value, not the index. You should either write `x=i**2`, or in the for loop you should specify it differently:

```
for i, value in enumerate(wholeList): 
    x = value**2
    tmp.append(x)
```

The `tmp` list now includes the square values of the `wholeList`.
Also, you are not printing anything somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have made this far more complicated than it really is. You can (should) use a list comprehension thus:

```
def printSquare(n):
    print([x*x for x in range(1, n+1)])

printSquare(5)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```